# Mongodump not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I tried  Mongodump on AWS EC2 instance. There is no error,  but the files are not dumped.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo mongodump --host localhost:27017 --db test--out /var/backups/

connected to: localhost:27017
2017-01-19T01:56:05.608+0000 DATABASE: test  to     /var/backups/test
```

How to take a dump inside AWS EC2? The database is in `data/db` folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my mongodb folder first I made a folder for backups:
sudo mkdir backups

Then used 777 just in case, later I changed it to 766
sudo chmod 777 -R backups

***sudo mongodump -h*** ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com **--port 27017 --db** your_db_name_here **-u** your_username_here **-p** your_password_here **--out backups/**

Of course change your host also
and if you want backup zipped then add this
--oplog --gzip

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First you should set required permission for out directory

sudo chmod 777 -R /var/backups

then

sudo mongodump --port 27017 --db test --out /var/backups/

Answer (score 0):

**Take Mongodb backup (Aws DocumentDB)**

mongodump --host="Documentdb endpoint" --port=27017 -u "username" -p "" -d "dbname" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --gzip --archive > /path/dbname.gz

enter password

*Note*
--gzip: zip used in linux.

path: where you want to download the db zip file.